# Why does subscript 2 not appear on Windows XP?

Tags: .net, windows-xp, subscript

I am trying to display CO2 in a static text control on a .NET application, but on some Windows XP system, the subscript-2 (unicode 2082) appears as a square). I suspect that it may be a font issue as it appears on some Windows XP systems but not on all. It always displays on Windows 7 and Vista. It's available on MS Gothic font. Ideas very welcome.

Comment: What font does your label use?

Answer (score 2):

*MS Sans Serif* doesn't contain Unicode character U+2082, therefore the glyph will only be rendered as a square. To solve the problem you need to use a character where U+2082 is available.

You can check all available characters with Window's charmap.exe utility. *MS UI Gothic* for instance contains this character, as well as *Segoe UI* or *Arial Unicode MS*.