# Why Unicode subscript symbol is not properly displayed in C# Label?

Tags: c#, unicode, fonts, windows-xp, subscript

I have a C# Label and I set the text to the String "CO\u2082" (CO2 with the Unicode subscript) .

The label is displayed properly on my PC which runs Windows XP service pack 3, but not displayed properly on a PC with Windows XP service pack2.

```
m_labelDescCO2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();  
m_labelDescCO2.Text = "CO\u2082";
```

The Label font is defined to be Microsoft Sans Serif.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Doesn't work for me on XP SP3 either... It works in WPF, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the font that you've selected doesn't support Unicode subscript characters on XP service pack 2.

Have a look [here](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/superscripts_and_subscripts.html) for some information regarding Unicode support.

I think that you'll have to check for a different font.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it's a font problem.

It doesn't work with MS Sans and Verdana, it does work with Arial Unicode MS

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081137/why-does-subscript-2-not-appear-on-windows-xp).  Some fonts do not have superscript or subscript support in other operating systems. The "Character Map" program in Windows is a good point to start figuring out.